# Count unique characters in a String and group the counts

Tags: scala

The code counts the amount of unique characters that fit in the character set `ACGT` (*stemming from [nucleobases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleobase)*).

We take a string as input that must contain only either `'A'`, `'C'`, `'G'`, or `'T'`.

For instance, `"AACCC"` should return the Map that looks like this:
`Map('A' -> 2, 'C' -> 3, 'G' -> 0, 'T' -> 0)`.
More detail can be found in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/HeeL/87dc937a9a767dfd60fa) with specs.

```
class DNA(code: String) {
  val nucleotides = Map('A' -> 0, 'T' -> 0, 'C' -> 0, 'G' -> 0)

  code foreach valid_nucleotide

  def nucleotideCounts(): Map[Char, Int] = {
    nucleotides ++ code.filter(nucleotides.contains(_)).groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)
  }

  def count(nucleotide: Char): Int = {
    valid_nucleotide(nucleotide)
    nucleotideCounts()(nucleotide)
  }

  private def valid_nucleotide(char: Char) = {
    if (!nucleotides.contains(char)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("DNA is wrong");
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: So this is only for DNA? What if you wanted to support RNA?

Comment: idk, it was just a test task for learning purposes. I have no idea about RNA. What difficulties am I going to have when I try to add the RNA support in my code?

Comment: well... the allowed characters are different :)

Comment: then I will have to only modify a Map

Comment: I would suggest modfying the returned argument `"DNA is wrong"` to: `"Character not found in valid nucleotide set"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part, there isn't much that I would change - well done!

First, minor things:

1. Remove the semi-colon in valid_nucleotide.
2. Next, you can change `nucleotides.contains(_)` (an anonymous function) to just `nucleotides.contains` (a method value).
3. The reuse of `valid_nucleotide` in `count` will result in any call with an invalid parameter getting an `IllegalArgumentException("DNA is wrong")`. I think this error would be confusing in this context.

The biggest single change I would make is to precompute the nucleotide counts. Currently, the code recomputes them each and every time either `count` or `nucleotideCounts` is called. Since `code` is immutable, it is only necessary to compute them once.

In a Java program, the "empty" nucleotides map could be made into a static member (rather than having a copy of it in every instance of the `DNA` class). The equivalent approach in Scala is to use a *companion object* (an object with the same class name as the class it is a companion to).

My version of your code looked like this:

```
object DNA {
  val nucleotides = Map('A' -> 0, 'T' -> 0, 'C' -> 0, 'G' -> 0)
}

class DNA(code: String) {

  code foreach validNucleotide

  val counts = countNucleotides()

  def nucleotideCounts(): Map[Char, Int] = counts

  def count(nucleotide: Char): Int = {
    validNucleotide(nucleotide)
    nucleotideCounts()(nucleotide)
  }

  private def countNucleotides(): Map[Char, Int] = {
    DNA.nucleotides ++ code.filter(DNA.nucleotides.contains).groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)
  }

  private def validNucleotide(char: Char) = {
    if (!DNA.nucleotides.contains(char)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Character not found in valid nucleotide set")
    }
  }
}
```